# Exporting a database created via CodeFirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, ef-code-first

I've been working with MVC, CodeFirst and MySql Connector .NET for a while. Everything was working like a charm, so far.

But now, I'm facing a problem that I'm not being able to solve... For some reasons, I had to move the databases I'm using to another server. And I'm trying to do this in the simpler way: via .sql files.

After importing the databases' content to the new server, the database structure was fine. But when the website tries to access the content of the databases via EF, weird problems occurs (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown column 'Extent3.item' in 'field list')

Trying to find answers to solve my problem, I realized that this kind of problem occurs because of relationships that are not being created properly using FKs. But, In my case it does not apply since everything was working before I try to move the databases.

Then, just came to my mind that some info about the database schema is stored somewhere by the connector(actually, I don't know if this is true... But I think I read something like that somewhere). So, maybe, the problem is that I'm missing some information when I'm trying to export the database to .sql files.

So... I would like to know if I'm following the right steps in order to export and import my databases' content to the new server. If I'm not, how am I supposed to proceed? If I am, what can be the source of my problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What you can try is to do `.ToString()` on the query that causes the exception. This will give you the Sql query that is being generated for your query. Now run the Sql against the database and see if you have the same error. Analyze the Sql query and compare to your database schema. This should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Well, I've done what you suggested... And it didn't help me at all... When I use the query string in the old database, it works like a charm. But when I use it in the new database: "Unknown column 'Extent3.item' in 'field list'" happens. The funny thing is: There is no "Extent3" table in the old database... However, the query still works... I don't know what can be happening...

Comment: In the end, your suggestion helped me to find the error haha. Thanks, @Pawel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The servers have different SOs. The old one, was running Windows. The new one runs Linux. Case sensitive for table names is turned on by default in linux MySQL and the old database wasn't case sensitive. So, I only had to disable case sensitive table names in the new database.